# Cannot Execute File When Via Telnet

Tags: shared-libraries, embedded-linux, telnet

I use telnet to my embedded board and try to execute a file:

```
$> telnet 192.168.0.10
$> Connected.    
#> ./Test.exe
```

It gives error like:

> ./Test.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Yes, I know that binary uses `curl` and device has related libraries.
But If I connect to device directly using `GtkTerm` and execute, It runs without error.
Why can not It load shared libraries when telnet used?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of embedded board are you using? Is it possible that you have different security settings for connection via serial port and telenet?

Can you provide more information:

1.) Use [ldd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) during you connection via GtkTerm and telenet on your Test.exe and share the output:

```
$ ldd Test.exe
```

It will show if cURL's lib is properly linked.

2.) Let's check if there are some differences in PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables values depending on connection type (GtkTerm vs telenet):

```
$ echo $PATH
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

3.) You have written:

> #> ./Test.exe

does it means that you are executing this binary as root?

Comment: In host linux, `ldd` says: `not a dynamic executable`. There is no `ldd` in the board. `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are the same in both. Yes in board, i am root.

Comment: You received `not a dynamic executable` probably because your host OS is 64-bit and the binary is cross-compiled for 32-bit OS running on your board. Does the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on your board contains the directory where libcurl.so is located? What about other executables - can you run different binary (like /bin/ls) via telnet and see if it works? Third option - libcurl might fail this way if some of its dependencies aren't met but that would be strange as it works via GtkTerm. Is `ldconfig` available on your board?